# Order By Ascending with CamlBuilder()

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, caml-query, js

How to write a function to order by `ascending: true` for date field. There is a picture library in our site.

I find `.OrderByDesc('year')`, but I need it's opposite:

```
var query = new CamlBuilder()
        .View(['Title', 'Description', 'FileLeafRef','year']) 
        .Query().Where()
            .TextField('ContentType').EqualTo('EventsFolder')
            .OrderByDesc('year') //here
        .ToString()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just use OrderBy() this is Ascending (default sorting):

```
var query = new CamlBuilder()
        .View(['Title', 'Description', 'FileLeafRef','year']) 
        .Query().Where()
            .TextField('ContentType').EqualTo('EventsFolder')
            .OrderBy('year')
        .ToString()
```

[Great POST here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=camljs).